# User profile image can not show in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, image, user-profile, laravel-jetstream

I'm using laravel 8. I have used jetstream for user registration. Profile photo feature is being used, But it did not show profile image.

I help from you good people.

#coding

Comment: Do you mean you are uploading an image and it's not showing up? Like a not found error in the console?

Comment: no, it is in the user profile image which the user can update after registration

Comment: When you use your browser to inspect where the image should be showing up, what do you see? Is the path correct? Are there any relevant errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `APP_URL` is correct in your `.env` file including port. ie. if you are running on localhost and port 8000 your `APP_URL` should be `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

If the profile photo is stored successfully and that didn't work try:

1. Deleting the shortcut folder storage created at /project/public/
2. run `php artisan storage:link`

The photo should show up.